# Copying files to Fuchsia / Magenta kernel

Tags: fuchsia, magenta-kernel

How to copy files (e.g. ".o" or ".dart") from your host (Linux machine) to the Fuchsia / Magenta kernel? or is there any way to prepare your files -> save them to respective Fuchsia / Kernel directory -> Compile the kernel -> and when I boot, my files are there inside the kernel.

I have followed this link: [Copying files to and from Magenta / Including Additional Userspace Files](https://github.com/fuchsia-mirror/magenta/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md) but failed to complete the same.

Edit:

These two options are listed (Link which I posted earlier) in their official tutorial, but I am not able to follow them.

Question A: **Copying files to and from Magenta** (**Already figured out**)

With local link IPv6 configured, the host tool ./build-magenta-ARCH/tools/netcp can be used to copy files.

```
# Copy the file myprogram to Magenta
netcp myprogram :/tmp/myprogram

# Copy the file myprogram back to the host
netcp :/tmp/myprogram myprogram
```

- **Using this option I am able to copy files from my Linux machine to Fuchsia kernel, but when I restart the kernel,  my transferred files are gone. How to transfer files permanently?**

Question B: **Including Additional Userspace Files**

```
$BUILDDIR/tools/mkbootfs -o extra.bootfs @/path/to/directory

echo "issue.txt=/etc/issue" > manifest
echo "etc/hosts=/etc/hosts" >> manifest
$BUILDDIR/tools/mkbootfs -o extra.bootfs manifest
```

Comment: Does your failed task creates any log or output?

Comment: @nwildner - No Errors, but I am unable to understand the procedure which is given in their tutorial. Please check my edited question, and If you can help ..thank you in advance –